# I want to create a function in UNIX C to display the content of a file

Tags: exec, cat

I want to create a kind of agenda of championships and when a user logs in into my "database" he has to have access for visualising  the championships details. These kind of details i keep in a file. How should my function look like ? I think I should try to use something like 
define myFile="Desktop/Program/Visualize.txt"
and somehow in a function i should have something like 
 execlp("cat", "cat", myFile, 0);
Is there necessary using pipes or sockets? 
Thank you so much and please forgive my mistakes.

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Comment: I want a user to see the content of that file when he logs in..

Comment: Sorry tohava, hope now it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to go through system calls. Instead, use this function:

```
void display_file(const char *fn) {
    FILE *f = fopen(fn, "r");
    char c;
    while (1) {
        c = fgetc(f);
        if (c == -1)
            return;
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```